# SQL Server - Update Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update one column of one table as follows:

TB_Quest:

```
cod_1   cod_2   cod_3   Description  Value      Date
-----------------------------------------------------------------
123     181     6401    product A   7526836    19/02/2013
123     181     6401    product B   4638607    18/02/2013
123     181     6401    product C   9633450    06/02/2013
789     314     1361    product 1   6218035    15/02/2013
789     314     1361    product 2   6189032    14/02/2013
```

The result should be:

```
cod_1   cod_2   cod_3   Description   Value      Date
-----------------------------------------------------------------
123     181     6401    product A     7526836    19/02/2013
123     181     6401    product A     4638607    18/02/2013
123     181     6401    product A     9633450    06/02/2013
789     314     1361    product 1     6218035    15/02/2013
789     314     1361    product 1     6189032    14/02/2013
```

Does anyone know it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific problem do you have? Updating data is a basic operation, so it isn't clear what your difficulty is.

Comment: what is the basus of the description? latest date?

Comment: So are you saying that you need the latest [Description] of a set of codes to be applied to all previous versions of that same set of codes?

Comment: If so, then you should know that this implies that the table design is relationally incorrect.

Comment: If @RBarryYoung is correct about the method of updating description, disregard my answer...

Comment: RBarryYoung, you're right about "need the latest [Description] of a set of codes to be applied to all previous versions of that same set of codes". And no, the design is not incorrect, since this is only a part of a final table to be used in an webApp which will generate a customized report. By the way, don´t worry about the design. Just the simple query issue, ok?

Comment: @jMarcel - you may not think the design is important, but it may benefit others who read this question and want to avoid introducing problems like this into their database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't make it clear how you are choosing the values.  Here is one way:

```
with toupdate (
     select t.*, min(description) over (partition by cod_1) as minDescription
     from t
    )
update toupdate
    set Description = minDescription
```

It sets the description to the minimum value for each group defined by `cod_1`.  This fits the data in your question.

If you want the latest description, I would do that with a subquery:

[Problem uploading code]

```
update t
    set description = 
        (select top 1 description
         XXX
         where t2.cod_1 = t.cod_1
         order by date desc)
```

(Now, add a "from t t2" between the `select` and `where` in the subquery where the XXX is.)

Comment: It will work on SQL Server 2005 and 2008.  Window functions were not available before 2005.

Comment: thanks i was just clarifying because this statement `SUM(Val) OVER (ORDER BY Val)` will only work on 2012. `:)`

Comment: The solution is right, but you just forgot to associate the whole PK. Anyway, THANK YOU SO MUCH !
Solution: with t as (select * from  TB_Quest) update TB_Quest
set description = (select top 1 description from t x
where x.cod_1=cod_1 and x.cod_2=cod_1 and x.cod_3=cod_3
order by Date desc)

Answer (score 1):

```
    select cod_1, cod_2,   cod_3, max(Date) as date
    From TB_Quest
    group by cod_1, cod_2,   cod_3
```

join it to TB_Quest   with cod_1, cod_2,   cod_3, date for get the Description   and Update the the table join again the select with the table but only use cod_1, cod_2,   cod_3

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   update TB_Quest set Description =
      if (Description= 'product 2' , 'product 1' , 
      if(Description= 'product 1' , 'product 1',
      if (Description = 'product A' , 'product A' , 'product A' )))
```

[**DEMO SQLFIDDLE HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4797/1)

Comment: What about 'Product B' -> 'Product A'? I think he's looking for something that will update everything simultaneously.

Comment: This way is inviable, because there is too many descriptions already and they'll change along the week/month and many other brand new would be created. These 'product 1' etc is just a small example.

Comment: i have made this update query as you wanted , if you want something ,ore clarify it and i will  update my query to fit your desire

Comment: Never mind. If you want, check the solution by Gordon Linoff above.